# AIF wcf webservices integration in android

Tags: android, axapta

I want to use AIF webservices to connect to Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012. Because when I want to connect to the service using wsdl soap, it seems I am not authenticated in the system.
What is the best way to use AIF service?

Comment: Please include which kind of adapter you are using (HTTP, net.tcp, other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, AIF is exposed as WCF. You need to change the service settings to enable it as a SOAP service.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Azure Service Bus Relay and the "Developing Mobile Apps" white paper.

**Azure Service Bus Relay:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aif/archive/2013/04/29/aif-windows-azure-service-bus-adapter.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720290.aspx

**White Paper:**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38413